# Reading number from HTML adding a number and returning to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading a value from HTML adding 1 to that that number and then updating the number within the HTML. When I do this, it returns the number back into the HTML as `NaN`.

I've tried using `parseInt()` and `Number()` but I still get the same output.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inputForm">
            <form id="frm1" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">    
                <h3>Update League Table!</h3>
                <section class="playerOne">
                    <label for="playerOne">Player One Name:</label>
                    <select name="playerOne" id="playerOne">
                        <option value="name1">name1</option>
                        <option value="name2">name2</option>
                        <option value="name3">name3</option>
                        <option value="name4">name4</option>
                    </select>
                </section>
                <br>
                <section class="playerTwo">
                    <label class="playerTwoText" for="playerTwo">Player Two Name:</label>
                    <select name="playerTwo" id="playerTwo">
                        <option value="name1">name1</option>
                        <option value="name2">name2</option>
                        <option value="name3">name3</option>
                        <option value="name4">name4</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </section>
                <br>
                <section class="winner">
                    <span>Please select winner:</span>
                    <br>
                    <input id="userOne" type="radio" name="winnerWinner" value="userOne">
                    <label for="userOne">Player One</label>
                    <input id="userTwo" type="radio" name="winnerWinner" value="userTwo">
                    <label for="userTwo">Player Two</label>
                </section>
                <br>
                <section class="submission">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </section>
                <p id="submitComplete">testing</p>
                <p id="name1GP">0</p><p id="name1Wins">0</p>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function formSubmit() {
    var p1 = document.getElementById("playerOne").value;
    var p2 = document.getElementById("playerTwo").value;
    var radiobox = document.querySelector('input[name="winnerWinner"]:checked').value;
    if (p1 === "name1" && radiobox === "userOne") {
        var name1GP = document.getElementById("name1GP").value;
        name1GP += 1
        document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHTML = name1GP
    }
    return false;
}
```

The value I am reading is `id="name1GP"` I want to add `1` to this value and then return it to the HTML, however instead of returning `1` it returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph element doesn't have a .value. You need to get the innerHTML as an int.

```
if (p1 === "name1" && radiobox === "userOne") {
    var name1GP = parseInt(document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHTML);
    name1GP += 1
    document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHTML = name1GP
}
```

Comment: instead of innerHTML, I would suggest `.text()`

Comment: .text() would require jquery. His code is vanilla js, so I kept inline with that.

Comment: No worries @JackU, accept as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

A p tag is not supposed to have any value property, you should probably have used `var name1GP = parseInt(document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHTML, 10);`

```js
var val = document.getElementById('test').value;
console.log(val);

var val2 = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
console.log(val2, typeof val2);

var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML, 10);
console.log(val3, typeof val3);
```

```html
<p id="test">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
var name1GP = document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHtml;
name1GP = parseInt(name1GP) + 1
document.getElementById("name1GP").innerHTML = name1GP
```

Answer (score -1):

Values in HTML are rendered as strings.
A string + a number will result with `NaN`.

change your code to parse your string into a number:

`name1GP = parseInt(document.getElementById("name1GP").value)`

and that should do the trick.

Comment: A paragraph element doesn't have .value.